# How would I define the __builtin_blendvps256 GCC intrinsic in Ada using GNAT?

Tags: gcc, x86, ada, intrinsics, gnat

I am trying to define a library in Ada (built on GNAT specifically) for x86 ISA extensions. (This question is specific to AVX/AVX2).

Here is some example code below:

```
-- 256-bit Vector of Single Precision Floating Point Numbers
type Vector_256_Float_32 is array (0 .. 7) of IEEE_Float_32 with
  Alignment => 32, Size => 256, Object_Size => 256;
pragma Machine_Attribute (Vector_256_Float_32, "vector_type");
pragma Machine_Attribute (Vector_256_Float_32, "may_alias");

-- 256-bit Vector of 32-bit Signed Integers
type Vector_256_Integer_32 is array (0 .. 7) of Integer_32 with
  Alignment => 32, Size => 256, Object_Size => 256;
pragma Machine_Attribute (Vector_256_Integer_32, "vector_type");
pragma Machine_Attribute (Vector_256_Integer_32, "may_alias");

-- 256-bit Vector of 32-bit Unsigned Integers
type Vector_256_Unsigned_32 is array (0 .. 7) of Unsigned_32 with
  Alignment => 32, Size => 256, Object_Size => 256;
pragma Machine_Attribute (Vector_256_Unsigned_32, "vector_type");
pragma Machine_Attribute (Vector_256_Unsigned_32, "may_alias");

function vblendvps
  (Left, Right, Mask : Vector_256_Float_32)
   return Vector_256_Float_32 with
  Inline_Always => True, Convention => Intrinsic, Import => True,
  External_Name => "__builtin_ia32_blendvps256";
```

For the sake of education, I want to know how to do this in assembly.

I have tried to define the vblendvps function using the `Asm` function from `System.Machine_Code`. However, as I am not knowledgeable about assembly programming, I am struggling to find resources on how to do this.

This is what I have so far:

```
with System.Machine_Code; use System.Machine_Code;

function vblendvps
(Left, Right, Mask : Vector_256_Float_32)
return Vector_256_Float_32
is
result : Vector_256_Float_32;
begin
Asm
(Template => "vblendvps %3, %0, %1, %2",
 Outputs  => Vector_256_Float_32'Asm_Output ("=g", result),
 Inputs   =>
   (Vector_256_Float_32'Asm_Input ("g", Left),
    Vector_256_Float_32'Asm_Input ("g", Right),
    Vector_256_Unsigned_32'Asm_Input ("g", Mask)));
return result;
end vblendvps;
```

When compiling the complete code, I get

```
Error: too many memory references for `vblendvps'
```

I believe this means that I need to move the arguments from memory to registers, but I am not sure. If there are some helpful references that explain every instruction, I would greatly appreciate that. (I had quite some trouble looking up the arguments to `vblendvps`).

My understanding is that the instruction is of the form (from ymm registers in my case)

```
vblendvps RESULT, LEFT, RIGHT, MASK
```

Please let me know how I would do this. Even if it is not in Ada, I'm sure I can figure out how to translate it.

Comment: *since integer overflow is mostly ignored in C.* - Not "in C", only "by the designers of Intel's intrinsics API".  But also, on a 2's complement machine like x86, C's integer conversion semantics between signed and unsigned int make it a no-op, keeping the same bit-pattern.  (The value is modulo-reduced into the value-range of the target type, e.g. `-123` becomes `2**32 - 123U` and vice versa.)  So yeah, Intel's API design is pretty casual about that for `int` args, like there's only `_mm_set_epi32` not an unsigned version, forcing people to let their unsigned values get converted to signed.

Comment: But for Intel's `_mm256_blendv_ps (__m256 a, __m256 b, __m256 mask)`, the arg is actually a `__m256`, a vector of single-precision `float` elements.  Even though it's normally from a compare, so it's all-ones / all-zeros elements, although you can of course use it with the signs of actual floats instead of comparing against zero.  And integer vectors aren't signed or unsigned in Intel's API, just `__m256i`.  But I guess you're using the GNU C native API where there is an underlying element type.

Comment: The GNU C builtin is `v8sf __builtin_ia32_blendvps256 (v8sf,v8sf,v8sf);` so it matches Intel's API; the mask arg is single-precision floats, not integer.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html .  So just like with the intrinsics API, you need to convert vector types if using integers.  With Intel's API, `_mm256_castsi256_ps()` to reinterpret a `__m256` as a `__m256i`.  With GNU C native vectors, I think just `(v8sf)v`, unless that does int->float conversion instead of reinterpret.

Comment: @PeterCordes It seems that (at least when importing to Ada with the GCC compiler), I am unable to use the intrinsics immintrin.h which is why I am using the underlying GCC intrinsics.

Comment: Well sure, that makes sense; I wouldn't expect you to be able to use a C header in a different language.  I wrote it that way because I initially forgot that these were GNU native vectors and thus had an element type. >.<